# Buffer Overflow Return Address Attack

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am trying to learn more about buffer overflows so I have created a simple program to gain knowledge and try to exploit it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void failed(void)
{
    puts("Did not exploit");
    exit(0);
}

void pass(void)
{
    puts("Good Job");
    exit(1);
}

void foo()
{
    char input[4];
    gets(input);
}

int _main()
{
    foo();
    failed();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to fill the buffer within `foo()` with random characters as well as the address of `pass()` such that the return address of `foo()` gets overwritten to the starting address of `pass()`. Using the GDB commands as follows to get relevant information.

`x foo`
-> 0x8049dd7 foo :    0xfb1e0ff3

### `disas foo`

```
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x08049e09 <+0>:    endbr32
   0x08049e0d <+4>:    push   %ebp
   0x08049e0e <+5>:    mov  %esp,%ebp
   0x08049e10 <+7>:    push   %ebx
   0x08049e11 <+8>:    sub  $0x14,%esp
   0x08049e14 <+11>:    call   0x8049e5a <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x08049e19 <+16>:    add $0x9b1e7,%eax
   0x08049e1e <+21>:    sub $0xc,%esp
   0x08049e21 <+24>:    lea -0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x08049e24 <+27>:    push   %edx
   0x08049e25 <+28>:    mov %eax,%ebx
   0x08049e27 <+30>:    call   0x8058850 <gets>
   0x08049e2c <+35>:    add $0x10,%esp
   0x08049e2f <+38>:    nop
   0x08049e30 <+39>:    mov -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08049e33 <+42>:    leave  
   0x08049e34 <+43>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I then created a python program which feeds its output into my vulnerable.c program as printing simply

```
print('A'*15 + '\x08\x04\x9d\xd7')
```

The A*15 is supposed to fill the buffer and the EBP then overwrites the return address with the address of foo (\x08\x04\x9d\xd7) but I continue to get segmentation faults. Any assistance would be great!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @emetsipe what is the correct way using GDB to get the function address of `pass()` and what would need to be modified in my python program to correctly overwrite the return address of `foo()`

Answer (score 0):

Any mistake and the attempt will segfault.  You must:

- have the right target address
- put it in the right place on the stack
- use the right byte order

The first one is difficult because the kernel will randomize address spaces on load,
primarily because of these kinds of attacks.

The other two you've gotten wrong.

If you'd like to play with something similar, here's an example
that changes the return address.  Because of C calling conventions,
the stack is corrupted at the end of main, which can be fixed by using
stdcall or pascal calling conventions for the test function.
Syntax for that is compiler dependent.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void oops() {
    printf("oops!\n");
}

void /*__stdcall*/ test(int t)
{
    /* x86 stack is top down, int is same size as pointer */
    int *return_is_at = &t - 1;

    /* replace parameter with our return address, for oops to return to */
    *(&t) = *return_is_at;  /* just-in-case avoid optimization*/

    /* replace our return address with address of oops */
    *return_is_at = (int)oops;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    test(1);
    printf("test returned\n");
    /* unless stdcall, at this point our stack is corrupted 
       and this return will crash, so: 
    */
    exit(1);
}
```

Here's an alternative function that uses a local variable to calculate
the return address location intead of the parameter.
This assumes a standard stack frame, which the compiler may optimize away.
It also corrupts the stack.

```
void test2()
{
    /* x86 stack is top down, int is same size as pointer */
    /* this relies on consistently defined stack frames */
    int l;
    int *return_is_at = &l + 2;

    /* copy our return address up one, 
       for oops to return to (corrupting the stack) 
    */
    return_is_at[1] = *return_is_at;

    /* replace our return address with address of oops */
    *return_is_at = (int)oops;
}
```

FYI - It's possible to use a similar technique to track unique call trees for a function
(by walking up the stack frames) in order to fail specific call instances during testing.

Comment: In general, taking into account your 3 steps listed. What is the correct way to gdb the address of pass() assuming it wouldn't ever change and what would be the correct way of overwriting the return address in the stack of foo to be that of pass. In x86 it is little endian so I'm not sure if my print statement in my python program is printing it in little endian. (Compiled c program using `gcc -w -m32 -static -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector -z execstack test.c`)

Comment: 1) Asking gdb for the address will work for the current run, but probably not the next one.  

2) The stack frame has got lots of extra stuff in there. `lea -0xc(%ebp)` is a clue suggesting the return address would 16 bytes from the start of the input buffer (you'll have to experiment to be sure) .

3) Python is just printing the string bytes that you ask it to print.  LSB means low byte first, so if the return address is 0x01020304 your string bytes need to be `\x04\0x03\0x02\0x1'.

Comment: as far as i've noticed using those compile flags (idk which, just googled it) has caused the addresses to always remain the same no matter the run (this is also being executed on a VM with nothing else on it) I had been assuming the return address is 16 bytes from the start of the input buffer hence why my python print statement does `A*16 + {return address}` A is supposed to be the filler for for those 16 bytes then the return address. Assuming the return address doesn't change between runs (for simplicity) am I executing the correct gdb command for getting the function address? `x foo`

Comment: Also 0xc is HEX for 12 so do you mean that the return address would be 12 bytes after the input start rather than 16?

Comment: I don't use gdb regularly, but x is the display command, `x5i foo` should show the first 5 instrunctions of foo.  0xc is 12 but the saved ebp is also on the stack between the buffer and the return address.

Comment: It seems that I am doing just about everything right then, my `pass()` address is 0x08049dd7 so I must be doing something with the python print statement `print('A'*16 + '\xd7\x9d\x04\x08')` which is still causing it to seg fault. A*16 for buffer and edp space, then return address in LSB form.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use gdb and step up to the return instruction and look at what's there on top of the stack when it returns.  There's no substitute for actually looking.